# What happened to the derelict spaceship between the 'Alien' movies?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, aliens-1986

In Alien, we saw that the derelict ship was filled with eggs, however in 'Aliens' we are told that LV-426 is now inhabited by colonists. Since the derelict was full of eggs Weyland-Yutani shouldn't be hunting for new eggs, but they are doing this.

As I remember, the Nostromo was detonated in space - not on the surface of planet (where it could have damaged the derelict ship on the surface) so what could have happened to the Jockey's spaceship in between the two films?

Comment: What "Jokey's" ship are you referring to ?  The Nostromo crew went down in a separable craft which they also left in.  Who or what is 'Jokey' and what makes you think it crashed on LV-426 ?

Comment: @Stan - Typo for "jockey"; http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Jockey-Xenomorph

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fact that you've almost certainly seen the theatrical cut of the film which doesn't contain the deleted "Hadley's Hope" scene at the start.

This scene shows a family of colonists (named in the novelisation as Russ, Ann and little Timmy Jorden as well as their daughter Rebecca "Newt" Jorden) re-discovering the derelict and inadvertently bringing a face-hugger into the colony.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just saw Capt. Hollister of Red Dwarf fame walking around with a coffee cup and a sweat stain (1 minute into the clip), but Mac McDonald doesn't appear in the credits and his IMDB entry makes no references to *Aliens.*

Comment: @MajorStackings - It's a deleted scene. Those credits often get lost, especially if it was a test filming.

Comment: no suprise they have deleted this scene - family trip for facehugger eggs lol

Comment: @Qbik - Newt is my favourite character. Mostly.

Answer (score 9):

The Weyland-Yutani Corporation was in contact with Ash on the Nostromo, so they were informed about the derelict ship and its cargo, but apparently the information was filed away and forgotten since they never went back to investigate during the 57 years that Ripley was adrift in her escape pod.  The signal that led the Nostromo to LV-426 must have stopped broadcasting during that time, since nobody at the colony knew about the derelict.

It wasn't until after Ripley's rescue that Carter Burke read the coordinates of the derelict ship from her report and sent the colonists to investigate.  From [wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Aliens_(film)):

> **Ripley**: Oh, but they will know about it, Burke. From me. Just like they'll know that you were responsible for the deaths of 157
>   colonists!
>
> **Burke**: Wait a second—
>
> **Ripley**: You sent them to that ship!
>
> **Burke**: You're wrong!
>
> **Ripley**: I just checked the colony log, directive dated 6/12/79, signed Burke, Carter J. You sent them out there and you didn't even
>   warn them! Why didn't you warn them, Burke?
>
> **Burke**: Okay, look. What if that ship didn't even exist? Did you ever think about that? I didn't know! So now, if I went and made a
>   major security situation out of it, everybody steps in. Administration
>   steps in, and there are no exclusive rights for anybody; nobody wins.
>   So I made a decision, and it was wrong. It was a bad call, Ripley. It
>   was a bad call.